# Вместо запуска redux action функции, возвращается код

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hook

Столкнулся с проблемой в моем pet проекте, у меня авторизация работает вместе с redux. Проблема в том что action не запускается, а возвращает код в таком виде(засунул его в console log) [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Самое интересное в том что выше тоже есть action функция, она работает исправно(возвращает undefined).

Вот весь код:

```js
// auth actions
// right action
export const fetchAuthData = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<authAction>) => {
    try{
      dispatch({type: "AuthFetch", user: null, loading: true, message: "Fetching"})
      const response = await Fetch.auth.getUserData()
      console.log("here")
      if(response.body) {
        const {username, userType} = response.body
        dispatch({type: "AuthSuccess", user: {username, userType}, loading: false, message: null})
      }else if(response.message){
        dispatch({type: "AuthError", user: null, loading: false, error: response.message})
      }else {
        throw "Something went wrong"
      }
    }catch (err) {
      dispatch({type: "AuthError", user: null, loading: false, error: `${err}`})
    }
  }
}

// wrong action
export const loginAction = (payload: ILogin) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<authAction>) => {
    try {
      console.log("wth?");
      dispatch({type: "AuthFetch", user: null, loading: true, message: "Fetching"})
      const response = await Fetch.auth.login(payload)
      console.log(payload)
      if(response.status === "success") {
        fetchAuthData()
      }else {
        throw response.message
      }
    }catch (err) {
      dispatch({type: "AuthError", user: null, loading: false, error: `${err}`})
    }
  }
}

//actions index
import * as authActions from "./auth";

export const Actions = {
  ...authActions,
}

// authReducer
const defaultState: IAuthState = {
  user: null,
  loading: false,
  message: null
}

export const authReducer = (state: IAuthState = defaultState, action: authAction): IAuthState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AuthFetch":
      return {user: action.user, loading: action.loading, message: action.message}
    case "AuthSuccess":
      return {user: action.user, loading: action.loading, message: action.message}
    case "AuthError":
      return {user: action.user, loading: action.loading, message: action.error}
    default: return state
  }
}

// reducers index
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {authReducer} from "./authReducer";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

// store index
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {rootReducer} from "./reducers";

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

// useAction hook
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {Actions} from '../store/actions'

export const useActions = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
}
```

Благодарю за внимание

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в импорте, ide автоматом импортировал с файла. Нужно было импортировать с хука